# Twitter API - get  users which are common in my following and followers list

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, twitter

I am developing a twitter API

I am using REST API using ruby Oath GEM

I need to get all users which are common in my `following` and `followers` list.

What api can i use?

Thanks
Sreeraj

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy! Just perform a !diff between the two lists.

In other words, get both lists, and iterate over each entry/person, remove the differences, and viola!

Comment: but it is not easy to do if there are thousands of records, And also we are limted upto 350 calls per hour

Comment: @Sreeaj, you would use the same method, calling the same function. It is not any more difficult processing people with 10000 followers than it is with 1 follower. The API call rate limit is in place so that you do not abuse Twitter servers. With 350 API calls, that would mean you can cross-check 61,075 people. You need to work with what you have.